# undefined local variable or method `provider' for OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: twitter, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I'm following a tutorial for Devise+Omniauth+Rails 4 with multiple providers.  My code is very close to the examples at the [sourcery tutorial](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/) except that I've left off the confirmable module and changed linkedin to google_oauth2.

Everything is working fine until I get to the callback and then rails raises this error:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `provider' for #<OmniauthCallbacksController:0x007fa8312a5298>:
  (eval):7:in `twitter'
```

Here's my OmniauthCallbacksController (nearly identical to the link above):

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

  [:twitter, :facebook, :google_oauth2].each do |provider|
    self.provides_callback_for provider
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following line:

```
set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
```

To:

```
set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
```

Note the curly brackets around `#{provider}`, and it also needs to be stringified since the argument is passed in as a symbol.

Comment: Thanks! Also had some trouble with this producing a double rendering error.  I managed to get past that by removing the set_flash_message entirely and setting it before the redirect with flash[:notice] = "blahblah".